# java uses or overrides a deprecated API error

Tags: java, deprecated

Hello so this is my code, somehow I still get error down there I described error, any help would be appreciated. I am not really expert with import of this and especially API itself

```
   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MyClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File file = new File("Sinatra.txt");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            if (dis.available() != 0) {
                // Get the line.
                String s = dis.readLine();
                // Put words to array.
                String[] sParts = s.split(" ");
                // Initialize word longest length.
                int longestLength = 1;
                for (String strx : sParts) { // Go through each sPart, the next one is called strx
                    // If the document has word longer than.
                    if (longestLength < strx.length())
                        // Set new value for longest length.
                        longestLength = strx.length();
                }
                // Because array index from "0".
                int[] counts = new int[longestLength + 1];
                for (String str : sParts) {
                    // Add one to the number of words that length has
                    counts[str.length()] += 1;
                }
                // We use this type of loop since we need the length.
                for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Result:
    //        1 letter words: 0
    //        2 letter words: 2
    //        3 letter words: 0
    //        4 letter words: 1
    //        5 letter words: 0
    //        6 letter words: 2
    //        7 letter words: 2
    //        8 letter words: 0
    //        9 letter words: 3
```

Hello this is my code and when I try to compile it I get
error saying:

```
Note: MyClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: 1) it's not an error and 2) recompile with the command-line option -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: _italic_**bold** `javac MyClass.java -Xlint:deprecation
MyClass.java:17: warning: [deprecation] readLine() in DataInputStream has been deprecated
            String s = dis.readLine();
                          ^`


This is what I get

Comment: Also you haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are not errors, they are warning, your code compiled.

To explain these lines :

> Note: MyClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

You are doing a call of `DataInputStream#readLine` which is deprecated since JDK 1.1 as per the documentation :

> **Deprecated.**
>   This method does not properly convert bytes to
>   characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is
>   via the BufferedReader.readLine() method. Programs that use the
>   DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the
>   BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:

```
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
```

with:

```
BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

As for the second line :

> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

It simply tells you the option to use when compiling to get more details about where you are using deprecated stuff.

**Edit :**

As per your comment, here how your code would looks like :

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;//Add these two imports
import java.io.BufferedReader;
...
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));//Use BufferedReader as suggested by the doc instead of DataInputStream
...
String s = br.readLine();//Read with the non-deprecated readLine of BufferedReader
```

Comment: Hey when i swap these 2 I just get whole bunch of "cannot find a symbol"

Comment: Do you know maybe how exactly my code should look like since I get confused and I get a lot of cannot find symbol

Comment: Savard
Hey I did it but I still have one error

When I type in line 18 program doesn't recognise br

if ( br.available() != 0) {

Comment: Select `Analyze > Inspect Code` to run **lint** on your project

Answer (score 2):

From the DataInputStream API documentation:

> readLine()
>
> Deprecated.
>
> This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the BufferedReader.readLine() method. Programs that use the DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:
>
> `DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);`
>
> with:
>        `BufferedReader d
>             = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));`

So as you can see, in line `String s = dis.readLine()` in your code, you use a deprecated method. This means that there is a better option for doing what you're doing (as highlighted above). Even though the method is deprecated, it likely will work in some cases. But it isn't guaranteed to fulfill its contract anymore, and therefore it is better to use the similar but consistent `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.

Answer (score -1):

If this warning is showing up, you just uninstall your current jdk and delete its path from environment variables. And install jdk version 8(8u301) and set path again in environmental variables.

This method solved my problem

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful advice.  The "uses or overrides a deprecated API" warning has a specific cause.  If installing an older version of Java has made the warning go away, you haven't fixed the problem.  You've actually just put off fixing the problem for the next person to do.   And for the specific example in this question ... *it will not work at all* ... because the method was deprecated a long time ago.